# Finding the index number for a string of words

Tags: python, indexing

I'm creating a program in python that will go through a list of sentences and find the words in capitals within the sentences. I've used a findall function to acquire the capitals at the moment.

Here is an example of the output I am receiving at the minute:

```
line 0: the dog_SUBJ bit_VERB the cat_OBJ
['S'] ['U'] ['B'] ['J'] [] ['V'] ['E'] ['R'] ['B'] [] ['O'] ['B'] ['J']
```

However, I want for the output to be full words, as so:

```
['SUBJ'] [] ['VERB'] [] ['OBJ']
```

I also want the indices of the words as so:

```
['SUBJ'] [0]
['VERB'] [1]
['OBJ'] [2]
```

Is it possible to do this? I've seen the above done before on in the terminal and I think that 'index' is used or something similar?

Here's my code below (as far as I have got):

```
import re, sys
f = open('findallEX.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
ii=0
for l in lines:
    sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii, l))
    ii = ii + 1
    results = []
    for s in l:
        results.append(re.findall('[A-Z]+', s))
```

Thanks! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be careful as your regular expression will match capital letters in proper nouns/start of sentences etc.  For robustness I would also match the underscore as well `m = re.findall('_[A-Z]+',string)`.  The underscore is always leading so easy to remove with string slicing `m = [x[1:] for x in m]`

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
>>> s = 'the dog_SUBJ bit_VERB the cat_OBJ'
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import count
>>> zip(re.findall('[A-Z]+', s), count())
[('SUBJ', 0), ('VERB', 1), ('OBJ', 2)]
```

Format as appropriate...

Comment: without using itertools: `list(enumerate(re.findall('[A-Z]+', s)))`

Comment: @root yup - if the OP is going to format the tuple then it doesn't really matter at which position the index goes anyway...

Comment: Slight modification to @root's code: `list(enumerate([x[1:] for x in re.findall('_[A-Z]+',l)]))`. Now works with 'The dog_SUBJ bit_VERB Cat_OBJ` and similar.

Comment: @ejrb slicing not required - just have the `_` as non-capturing and capture group the rest: `(?:_)([A-Z]+)`

Comment: @ejrb yeah - not 100% sure why I put the non-capture in there now, but anyway, between us I think we got there ;)